# Ubuntu 18.04 Touchpad detection issue

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, lenovo

I have seen this issue before on different forums and I understand Lenovo laptops aren't fully supported. However my touchpad sometimes works, I am a relatively new linux user, I first tried ubuntu 16.04LTS now 18.04LTS both 64bit, I have a feeling something wrong happened during upgrading.

When I boot laptop I get this **error** **two times:**

```
error: no symbol table. Press any key to continue...
```

Then it takes around 5 minutes to boot into login, on 16.04 it barely took seconds.

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```